# Add custom class to wishlist top link

Tags: php, css, xml, magento, templates

I'd like to add a custom class to the wishlist link for styling.

I tried changing wishlist.xml to this :

```
<reference name="top.links">

        <block type="wishlist/links" name="wishlist_link" />
        <action method="addLinkBlock"><blockName>wishlist_link</blockName><prepare/><liParams>class="test"</liParams><position>10</position></action>
    </reference>
```

but the class is not set

I also tried changing code/core/Mage/Wishlist/Block/Links.php to this :

```
protected function _toHtml()
{
    if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) {
        $text = $this->_createLabel($this->_getItemCount());
        $this->_label = $text;
        $this->_title = $text;
        $this->_aParams = 'class="test"';
        $this->_url = $this->getUrl('wishlist');
        return parent::_toHtml();
    }
    return '';
}
```

but the class it still not set.

Here is my links.phtml file :

```
<?php $_links = $this->getLinks(); ?>
<?php if(count($_links)>0): ?>
<ul class="links"<?php if($this->getName()): ?> id="<?php echo $this->getName() ?>"<?php endif;?>>
<?php $i=0; ?>
<?php foreach($_links as $_link): ?>
    <?php if ($_link instanceof Mage_Core_Block_Abstract):?>
        <?php echo $_link->toHtml() ;?>
    <?php else: ?>
        <?php $i++; ?>
        <li class="<?php if($_link->getIsFirst()): ?>first<?php elseif($_link->getIsLast()): ?>last<?php else: ?>menu<?=$i?><?php endif; ?>" <?php echo $_link->getLiParams() ?>><?php echo $_link->getBeforeText() ?><a href="<?php echo $_link->getUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_link->getTitle() ?>" <?php echo $_link->getAParams() ?>><?php echo $_link->getLabel() ?></a><?php echo $_link->getAfterText() ?></li>
    <?php endif;?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

In result, wishlist is the only top link with no class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting, ok never tested this but it don't cost a lot to try it ;)

In your layout file:

```
<reference name="wishlist_link">
    <action method="setAParams">
        <param><![CDATA[class="myclass"]]></param>
    </action>
</reference>
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks. I'm new to Magento and I've been fighting so long with this little thing! Is there a way of changing the position using the same logic?

Comment: Yes layouts are powerfull with their action tags. I've edited my answer, please check ;)

Comment: If my edit don't work, i'm afraid you will have to override Mage_Wishlist_Block_Links class in your own module and change the $_position property

Comment: It doesn't seem to affect the position with XML.
I'll override then. Thanks for your time!

Comment: You're welcome, upvoted your question for good formatting ;). Strange that setPosition don't work, it should do the trick too, maybe double check your cache ? Ok after thinking it seems normal, i think when we call <reference> to the block, the block is already in top.links block so positon property is already "consumed" by top.links block